# getting authentication error on mount_smbfs

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, authentication, mount

I am trying to copy a file from MAC to windows using mount_smbfs. However, I am getting an authentication error. It says "server rejected connection: authentication error".  I am writing the correct username and password but the problem did not change. Here is my code below.

```
NSTask* task = [[NSTask alloc] init];
[task setLaunchPath:@"/sbin/mount_smbfs"];
[task setArguments:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"//user:50000@smb://192.168.2.1/Share",@"/Users/Shared", nil]];
[task launch];
```

Could you please help how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Probably unrelated, but shouldn't there be an initial slash in `@"Users/Shared"` ?

Comment: @MartinR I edited my code in my original code there is an initial slash you are right!

Comment: While there is code here, this question is not really a programming question, but rather about how correctly to use `mount_smbfs`. That makes it a better fit for apple.se or superuser.

Answer (score 3):

From [this page](https://web.archive.org/web/20150805074215/http://www.dejadejoder.com/blog/posts/2010/07/21/mac-osx-10-6-snow-leopard-mount_smbfs-authentication-error-problem/) - you need to specify the workgroup as part of the connection, otherwise you always get the authentication error.

so the connection string should be:

```
//WORKGROUP;user:50000@192.168.2.1/Share
```

... assuming that the `50000` is the password for the user `user`

Bear in mind that it's an URL that you're using, so make sure to URL-escape the username and the password before embedding them in the string, otherwise they could be misinterpreted.

If you're connecting to non-domain joined systems, then the `WORKGROUP` value is pretty much arbitrary, and tends to be ignored for the connection. It may matter for domain-joined systems, because the username is a `DOMAIN\username` but when you're connecting to non-domain systems the `DOMAIN\` part is ignored when checking user credentials.

Comment: It just needs the string to be present - I don't think you actually need to have the workgroup of the server there. I can connect to arbitrary samba systems that have different workgroup values using the same string

Comment: The only time that `WORKGROUP` may be an issue is with domain-joined systems

Comment: I tried and I did not get an authentication error but the file was not copied too. I am getting the error server connection failed: no root to host.

Comment: If you're copying a file to a remote system, you need to ensure that the remote share permits *writing* as well as reading.

Comment: There was a typo in my original answer, you *MUST NOT* have the `@smb://` in the connection string, if you do then it tries to connect to a system called `smb`

Comment: I apply the system to everyone can read and write. And I removed `@smb://` part but the result same.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22066/discussion-between-answer88-and-petesh)

Comment: That link is now dead, archive: https://web.archive.org/web/20150805074215/http://www.dejadejoder.com/blog/posts/2010/07/21/mac-osx-10-6-snow-leopard-mount_smbfs-authentication-error-problem/